# QLabel associated to a PushButton doesn't appears

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to build a `QLabel` that I'd like to appear when I press a `QPushButton`; code is simple:

```
    void Mod28::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
       AddItem();
    }
    void Mod28::AddItem()
    {
       QLabel *label_n = new QLabel(this);
       label_n->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label_n"));
       label_n->setGeometry(QRect(20, DimVert, 25, 17));
       label_n->setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);
       label_n->setNum(ItemCounter);
     }
```

Nothing appears. Instead, if I put `AddItem()` inside the following:

```
    Mod28::Mod28(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Mod28)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        AddItem(); // here, for example, is ok !!!!
    }
```

How can I solve? I need a `QLabel` appearing when I press the button.

Comment: Add your label to a `QWidget`.

Comment: Despite the fact that your label is not inserted into a layout of a widget, did you check that your `on_pushButton_clicked` is actually connected to the `QPushButton`'s signal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to call `label_n->show ();`  `label_n->raise();` after.

Answer (score 3):

Add your label to the widget that you want to show in it.

for example this line add lable to centralWidget layout:

```
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(label_n);
```

your function:

```
void Mod28::AddItem()
{
   QLabel *label_n = new QLabel(this);
   //
   //
   //
   ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(label_n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not yet solved! Last line:  
        ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(label_n); 
causes a crash and program exits...

Comment: I guess your central widget has no layout. add a widget with layout to your form with designer and try to add label to it.